# Inline style based off JSON value React

Tags: css, json, reactjs

I am pulling in JSON and mapping it successfully in a React component. However one of the JSON values is a HEX and I want to apply that HEX as an inline style to the background color of one of my `div`s.

I have tried a bunch of ways but I though it could be done like this.

```
<div className="ribbon-wrapper">
 <div className="ribbon" style={{backgroundColor: {item.color.tint}}}></div>
</div>
```

This throws a `Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ,` error. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `style` value is a Javascript object so you don't need to escape `item.color.tint`. You can pass it in directly:

```
<div className="ribbon" style={{backgroundColor: item.color.tint}}></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just directly pass it without brackets like this

```
<div className="ribbon" style={{backgroundColor: item.color.tint}}></div>
```